# Using for loop for asynctask

Tags: java, android

i have an asyntask that sends a request and receives images. it works fine for 1 item, the thing is here i have this method:

```
  Arraylist<String> todownload;
   .
   .

    public void downloadit(){


    int size=todownload.size();
     for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
          this.todo=todownload.get(i);
            System.out.println("Dowloading = " + todo);
    MyAsyncImagesDownload sync = new MyAsyncImagesDownload();
 System.out.println("Size="+todownload.size());
    sync.execute();

     }
```

to make it work for downloading more than 1 request. but let say the todownload has 2 values inside, the value of todo which is the one who Async works with, at the server is always the last one, i also tried to replace the for loop with:

```
for(String todo:Todownload)
.
.
```

still same thing. so i felt the loop is finishing its job before the execute job is finished, so i added Wait method to after execute and Notifyall() to the end of async task, but seems i get some errors with that. could you please help me what can i do to achieve this? thanks

Async code is :

```
BufferedOutputStream bos;  
    OutputStream output;  
    DataOutputStream dos; 
    int len;  
    int smblen;   
    InputStream in;  
    DataInputStream clientData; 
    FileOutputStream fos; 
    String filepath;
    String target;
    Socket clientSocket;




     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... Result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



String REresponse = null; 


Log.i("lifemate","im here in the Async !");
try {
    socket = new Socket(server, 1450);
} catch (UnknownHostException e5) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e5.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e5) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e5.printStackTrace();
}

String msg = "Connection accepted " + socket.getInetAddress() + ":" +    
 socket.getPort();
  Log.i(LOGTAG, msg);

   try {
    sInput  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
} catch (StreamCorruptedException e4) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e4.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e4) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e4.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
} catch (IOException e3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e3.printStackTrace();
}

try {


sOutput.writeObject(todo);

received=false;

} catch (IOException e2) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e2.printStackTrace();
 }

try {
sOutput.flush();
} catch (IOException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e1.printStackTrace();
}
    //Log.i(LOGTAG,"this"+rdytosplit);

while(received==false)
{



 clientSocket = socket;

try {
in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
} catch (IOException e2) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e2.printStackTrace();
} 

clientData = new DataInputStream(in); //used    
// clientBuff = new BufferedInputStream(in); //use    
System.out.println("i have started");

int N=1;
while(N==1){    

   System.out.println("Starting...");    




           int fileSize = 0;
            try {
                fileSize = clientData.read();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }        
           fileSize = (fileSize > 0) ? fileSize :0; 
                                                                       // guard  
 against  
 negatives.
           List<File> files = new ArrayList<>(fileSize);          //store list of 
 filename from client directory        // Using List and <>
           List<Integer> sizes = new ArrayList<>(fileSize);       //store file size   
 from client 
         //Start to accept those filename from server

           for (int count=0;count < fileSize;count ++){  
               File ff = null;
                try {
                    ff = new File(clientData.readUTF());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
               files.add(ff);  
               filepath="storage/sdcard/Pictures/";




           }  

   for (int count=0;count < fileSize;count ++){  

           try {
                sizes.add(clientData.readInt());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
   }  

  for (int count =0;count < fileSize ;count ++){     

     len=sizes.get(count);  

   System.out.println("File Size ="+len);  



   try {
        output = new FileOutputStream(filepath + files.get(count));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }  
   dos=new DataOutputStream(output);  
   bos=new BufferedOutputStream(output);  

   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];    

   try {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } //This line is important  

   try {
        while (len > 0 && (smblen = clientData.read(buffer)) > 0) {   
            try {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, smblen);
            ////here you must add +1 value to imagechange_1 or ..._2
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
              len = len - smblen;  
              try {
                dos.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
   Log.i("downloader","job is done");
   N=2;

   try {
    dos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
   //// should i close in and clientdata now ?
  }



}   //end loop 
received=true;
}






try {
in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
socket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
Run=false;
disconnect();

return REresponse;

     }
```

}

Comment: What is `MyAsincImagesDownload`? And what class contains the `downloadit()` method?

Comment: its the main calss which contains downloadit() and first one is myAsync name ofcourse :)

Comment: Please post the code for `MyAsyncImagesDownload`.

Comment: The "async code" that you posted here will not compile because there are no class or method names. Please edit your code to help us understand more clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: well the whole code of this class is like 1000 rows, i dont think neither of us wants that here :(

Comment: Probably not, but you should at least provide some context so that we know what class and method contains the code you are showing. You should also narrow down the problem to the fewest lines of code as possible.

Comment: well found the solution,but the problem is about looping an async task mate, async tasks are all same unless a socket or some thing like that be closed inside the first loop mistakely ,else its all the same, thanks alot any way mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do the `looping` within in the `asynctask` instead of looping the `asynctask`:

```
private class MyAsyncImagesDownload extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        int count = urls.length;
        long totalSize = 0;

        //a loop can be like this
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
            publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
            if (isCancelled()) break;
        }
        return totalSize;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried, the result was amazingly fail, i think it sent 3 requests for 2 values of array, which 1 of them was null

Comment: oh i didnt try that like this ofcourse, lemme give it a shot

Comment: What does your loop look like in the `asynctask`

Comment: i tried to put whole doinBackground into the for loop

Comment: Don't loop the `asynctask`.

Comment: well if i had any other clue sure i would give it a try :D